# convert part of a webpage to a range

Tags: javascript

Suppose somewhere in my webpage I have a div tag with an id of "idDiv"  It has some text in it, and perhaps some linebreak tags, and images as well.  I want to obtain this div as a JavaScript document range.  How would I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you [consulted the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNode)?

Comment: I have looked.  I see if the user selects some words in his browser on his webpage, that it is very easy to convert that to a range.  I also see a document.CreateRange command, and I see that you can set the first and last node of that.  But suppose you have the div that I mentioned above.  What is the first node and last node in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you could select a node using:

```
Range.selectNode()
```

Full API how functions available on Range object is available here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

Just a note for whom is not familiar with `Range`.

A `Range` object is a fragment of a document that can contain nodes.
One of its common use, is for example, user text selection`of programmatic definition.

Answer (score 1):

As Hamms mentioned in the comments you are looking for [`Range.selectNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNode). Example:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var node = document.getElementById('idDiv');

range.selectNode(node);
```

Here, `range` will span the entire div (including the div itself).